# importing and exporting variables (read -p/input) using bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have the following structure:

```
1.sh
2.sh
3.sh
```

All of these scripts are altogether into all.sh

`1.sh` takes the variable (let's say... **answer**) from the user (input) and play with it in 1.sh script.

```
read -p 'Answer is :  ' answer
```

All I want is to export or import also the variable **answer** taken from the user in 1.sh to 2.sh and 3.sh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Have `1.sh` output the value of `$answer`: `echo "$answer"`, and capture that in a variable, then pass that as an argument to `2.sh` and `3.sh`:

   ```
   answer=$(1.sh)
   2.sh "$answer"
   3.sh "$answer"
   ```
2. Instead of executing the scripts, source them so that they are executed by the current shell, not in a new process. Then any parameters set in `1.sh` will be available to `2.sh` and `3.sh`.

   ```
   source 1.sh  # sets a value for $answer
   source 2.sh
   source 3.sh
   ```

   A slight variation is to run `export answer` inside `1.sh`; the result of that is you don't have to source the other two scripts:

   ```
   source 1.sh
   2.sh   # answer is inherited from the environment
   3.sh   # answer is inherited from the environment
   ```